# Spring Cloud: GIT с JDBC backend

Tags: git, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud

**Проблема:** У меня работает только JDBC **ИЛИ** GIT. Только что то одно. Если меняю свойство `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap` на `true` или `false`.

**Вопрос:** Как мне сконфигурировать приложение, чтобы работало JDBC **И** GIT?

Прикладываю содержимое *bootstrap.properties*.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: jdbc, git
  application:
    name: configuration-server
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      name: configuration-server
      server:
        jdbc:
          order: 1
        git:
          uri: <hidden>
          order: 2
    bus:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решение:** получилось совершенно случайно узнать, что при такой связке нужно использовать параметры для JDBC: APPLICATION, PROFILE и LABEL, такие же, по которым можно найти конфигурацию в GIT репозитории. При этом в обратную сторону - это работает иначе. То есть для получения конфигурации из GIT репозитория - не нужно создавать с нужными параметрами записи в БД. И это все, несмотря на то, что указан приоритет для JDBC высшим чем у GIT.